# Contain movement within the parent page Jscript

Tags: javascript, jscript

As you have all been so very helpful recently, i have a further question for those with the experience.

I wish to contain my draggable item within the parent page but, the script i have has no containment. How would i contain this to the parent page...

here is the code.

I would be very grateful for any advice as to how to set the left,right,top,bottom variables to the container width & height set within the parent page... if anybody has this advice please feel free to indulge yourself. thanks in advance.

```
  <!----container code----within parent page>
        <style>
        .container {
        position:relative top:0px;left:0px; width:100% height:100%; };
        </style>


             var selected = null ,
             leftside = 0, rightside = 900, 
             topside=0, bottom=600;


       var selected = null, // Object of the element to be moved
       x_pos = 0, y_pos = 0, // Stores x & y coordinates of the mouse pointer
       x_elem = 0, y_elem = 0; // Stores top, left values (edge) of the element

                // Will be called when user starts dragging an element
                function _drag_init(elem) {
                    // Store the object of the element which needs to be moved
                    selected = elem;
                    x_elem = x_pos - selected.offsetLeft;
                    y_elem = y_pos - selected.offsetTop;
                }

                // Will be called when user dragging an element
                function _move_elem(e) {
                    x_pos = document.all ? window.event.clientX : e.pageX;
                    y_pos = document.all ? window.event.clientY : e.pageY;
                    if (selected !== null) {
                        selected.style.left = (x_pos - x_elem) + 'px';
                        selected.style.top = (y_pos - y_elem) + 'px';
```

Recent added PARTIAL SOLUTION for all who needs to know....

Obviously this is very in the making and is not actually defined with a container area, but containment is by the variables set as leftside,rightside ect

To assign the width & height of the containment area and the width height of the object in most necessary but i am yet to assign variables for this... Need a little more understanding of this area of variables and implementation... But this is a quick fix for my own personal project. But will help others in my position to gain an advantage of understanding...

```
  if (x_pos-x_elem <=leftside){
    x_pos =leftside + x_elem;
   }

   if (x_pos >=rightside){
    x_pos =rightside-10;
   }

   if (y_pos-10 <=topside){ 
     y_pos=topside+10;
   }

   if (y_pos+400 >=bottom){ 
    y_pos=bottom-400;
   }


    // Destroy the object when we are done
        function _destroy() {
            selected = null;
        }

    // Bind the functions...
        document.getElementById('frame1').onmousedown = function () {
        _drag_init(this);
        return false;
    };
       document.onmousemove = _move_elem;
       document.onmouseup = _destroy;
```

here is a fiddle for any1 upto it. many thanks in advance.

https://jsfiddle.net/ar7k3gzw/

Comment: If anybody has any further advice around the Far right border and how to code it correctly i would be much obliged with the many tohers who will eventually find this solution...

Comment: Strange symptom though... The solution is working on my browser, But not in the fiddle . Go-figure....